# How can i crawl javascript/JSON mixed content by using Python BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl product data information from my wholesaler's website which uses Prestashop CMS and stuck with mixed JSON/Javascript content.
I wrote a script with python BeautifulSoup and requests.
I know theese are not efficient library's to deal with JS but i guess i don't need to use selenium because of the website's structure. There is a  tag at the bottom and gives me the every info i need. But there is a problem here because when i crawl that json-like code block, There is javascript functions and etc. It's been only 5 days since i started to learn python so i don't even know if my approach is true or not. I want to parse the JSON content to put it in DB.

Here is my code snippet to crawl data and print to screen;

https://codeshare.io/647ylz

And this is the respond i get.

https://codeshare.io/mPMV34

Thank you for reading and spending time for me.

I tried to use Regex to match patterns that resemble JSON structures by identifying characters like {, }, [, and ], It didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to use Regex to match patterns that resemble JSON structures by identifying characters like {, }, [, and ], It didn't worked.

Probably because the `{}` can be nested, and there's no regular expression capable of matching arbitrary nested `{}`.

The good news is that you don't need arbitrary depth! If you know there's never more than 3 levels of nesting, you can write a pattern that matches that:

```
import re, json
pattern = r'\{(?:[^{}]|NEST)+\}'
for i in range(3):
    pattern = pattern.replace('NEST', pattern)
matches = re.findall(pattern, script)
for match in matches:
    print(json.loads(match))

# {'id_attribute': '4196', 'id_attribute_group': '36', 'attribute': 'antartica_g', 'group': 'couleur'}
# {'id_attribute': '4197', 'id_attribute_group': '36', 'attribute': 'babe_pink', 'group': 'couleur'}
# {'id_attribute': '4201', 'id_attribute_group': '36', 'attribute': 'classic_black', 'group': 'couleur'}
# ...
# {'18268': {'attributes_values': {'36'...
```

Future improvements:

- handling errors on `json.loads` in case you match something non-JSON
- verifying how many levels of nesting you actually need

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Right now i am trying to implement your solution.

Comment: Hello again, When i tried your solution i got this result : https://codeshare.io/yNKvPn

i still couldn't convert it to json format.
https://imgur.com/a/veLlvDh

Comment: Because it's already parsed, and Python is printing the resulting objects. If you want the raw JSON, just replace `print(json.loads(match))` with `print(match)`, or save the matches to a list. Also note that the result is a sequence of JSON objects, so don't try to parse the output as a single JSON object.